# QT Creator: ошибка: QJsonDocument: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, qt5

Доброе!

Указываю в form.cpp:

```
#include "form1.h"
#include <QJsonDocument>
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
form1.cpp: ошибка: QJsonDocument: No such file or directory
 #include <QJsonDocument>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

ОС: Ubuntu 18.4
В /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore файлы лежат:

```
root@pavelpc:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore# ls *json*
qjsonarray.h  qjsondocument.h  qjsonobject.h  qjsonvalue.h
```

Что делаю не так?

UPD sbssalert.pro:

```
QT       += core gui network widgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = sbssalert
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        form1.cpp
HEADERS += \
        form1.h
FORMS += \
        form1.ui
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: покажите pro-файл

Comment: Добавил pro файл в вопрос